# Computer stutter / lag

Tags: windows-10, lag, microsoft-edge

Just throwing this out there see if you guys have any ideas as to what might be causing this. Every now and then my pc will start to stutter / lag but it's not constant, it's only really noticeable if i'm playing a game or i'm moving my mouse as it will stop for a millisecond and continue on. Hard to explain. I recorded a video of it happening which is linked below.

[Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/iICPwvSQm1Y) - Has been compressed too much, but if you put it in 0.5 speed it's more visible.

After the video I went through and closed non essential processes checking for a few seconds after each one, it only disappeared after closing Edge browser which is very odd in my opinion.

This stutter doesn't affect audio.

Comment: System specifications might help here.

Comment: Motherboard:
ASRock X370 Taichi AMD X370,
CPU:
AMD Ryzen 7 1700 (non OC),
Memory:
G.SKILL Trident Z RGB 32GB 3200Mhz,
OS Drive:
Samsung 500GB EVO PCIE,
Video Card:
ASUS STRIX GTX 1080TI O11G

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Netflix and it seems to only affect you if your refresh rate exceeds 60. I solved this by torrenting Netflix shows instead.

Comment: Do you have an explanation why that would help?

Comment: I've no idea to be honest. It seems to be a problem with DRM restricted media but I'm unsure whether it's a Windows or GPU driver issue.